# How to use Capybara sessions or remember a user login

Tags: ruby, session, testing, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I want to test a chat app with Minitest and Capybara. The app assigns a logged-in user a unique ID. This ID is embedded in the head of an html-document and calls a javascript script which is used to connect with a visitor to chat with him.

Now, the problem is that every time I log in with capybara the ID changes (as it is for every new user). But I need the ID to configure the test.html file so the chat is assigned to the right user.

How can I make Capybara remember my user that I created in my fixtures.yml? Is there even a way? I tried using sessions but I'm not sure how to do it exactly nor if that is the right approach....

Any help is highly appreciated!

Best,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Would opening two different sessions at the same time to test the chat between them solve your issue?  I'm unclear why you need to configure the html -- that's something your app should be doing just through using it in the tests.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it would but I am not sure... Ok so, I am opening a test.html file. This test file calls a java script. This javascript opens a chatbox. The chat has a specific user_id. This user id is configured in the javascript and retrieved from a user that is logged in. That is to say, I can log in to the app, get the user Id and put it into my test file. When a new user signs in, the user Id changes every time. What I need is to log in my user with capybara and with that ID that is created when Capybara logs the user in, configure the testfile. Or make capybara remember the user....

Comment: Is that clearer now? I'm sorry I know it's tricky, even to explain (=

Comment: Sorry, not really - for most chat app testing you would normally create two sessions, log different users into each session and then switch between sessions to initiate and test the chat functionality - needing to know the ID and manually creating test HTML doesn’t really fit with the idea of feature tests

Comment: hmm yea... I'll try that thank you very much.... But is there no way to have Capybara remember a logged in user when I run the test again?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by remember a user, capybara doesnt maintain any state - the DB should be reset between every test so cookies aren’t valid anymore. Anything you want to be repeatable needs to be setup via data in the DB (fixtures/factory bot/etc)

Comment: that's exactly what I meant.... I thought I might have been able to change that somehow.... but it makes sense of course..... I also already tried to hardcode the uid, but that didn't work.... I'll try it with sessions and come back here... Thanks for your help mate

Comment: You’re welcome - look at Capybaras  `using_session`